# How AutoGenerate classes with cakePHP 2.7.x?

Tags: cakephp-bake, cakephp-2.7

Seems like there is no documentation regarding it anywhere. any assist will be appreciated.

Comment: autogenerate? You mean model generator? More explanation please.

Comment: yes, model-controller and view (i had it with 1.3.x versions but the tutorial that they had about it is not on the web anymore)

Comment: Did you try this one? http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/console-and-shells.html

Comment: No! somehow google hid it from me :) thanks
(add it as an answer pls) @noc2spamツ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation  is available at http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/console-and-shells.html. Added this as an answer as per OP's suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not mistaken,what you mean is the Cake Console & Shell that can produce autogenerate code for Controller,Model & View for your application.

You can refer here for more info http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/console-and-shells.html.

You can use `'bake'` shell to generate your mvc structure.

Example:

```
$cake bake all
```

will output all possible table on your database like below

```
---------------------------------------------------------------
Bake All
---------------------------------------------------------------
Possible Models based on your current database:
1.posts
2.users
Enter a number from the list above,
type in the name of another model, or 'q' to exit
```

and if you put 1,then the result will come out like below:

```
Baking `index` view file...

Creating file /Applications/XAMPP/htdocs/AQMCorporate/aqmtest/View/Posts/index.ctp
Wrote `/Applications/XAMPP/htdocs/AQMCorporate/aqmtest/View/Posts/index.ctp`

Baking `view` view file...

Creating file /Applications/XAMPP/htdocs/AQMCorporate/aqmtest/View/Posts/view.ctp
Wrote `/Applications/XAMPP/htdocs/AQMCorporate/aqmtest/View/Posts/view.ctp`

Baking `add` view file...

Creating file /Applications/XAMPP/htdocs/AQMCorporate/aqmtest/View/Posts/add.ctp
Wrote `/Applications/XAMPP/htdocs/AQMCorporate/aqmtest/View/Posts/add.ctp`

Baking `edit` view file...

Creating file /Applications/XAMPP/htdocs/AQMCorporate/aqmtest/View/Posts/edit.ctp
Wrote `/Applications/XAMPP/htdocs/AQMCorporate/aqmtest/View/Posts/edit.ctp`

Bake All complete
```

There you go with CakePHP console & shell.